# what is the difference between event driven and domain driven design Microservices?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

What is event driven design and Domain driven design?
What are the specific benefits using of Domain driven design, event driven design in MicroServices.

Comment: What are your findings thus far? What patterns have you found available for Domain Driven design? When do you believe you should use event driven design vs domain driven design? What benefits do you see in microservices?

Comment: DDD defines a separate domain model for each subdomain. A subdomain is part of the domain. 
Microservice architecture - architect an application as a collection of loosely coupled, services.                                                                                            
    The microservice architecture enables the rapid, frequent and reliable delivery of large, complex applications. It also enables an organization to evolve its technology stack.

Comment: Can we use these both in one application.

Comment: Based on your comment above, could you use both in one application? DDD defines a methodology for structuring business logic. Microservice defines an architecture for structuring your applications. Can they co-exist?

Comment: @CPerson  My answer is yes, they can co-exist.  Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: What about Event Driven , this also structuring the business logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Event sourcing` as an implementation strategy for the persistence of state, e.g. of aggregates. This strategy should not be exposed beyond the boundaries of aggregates. The events from event sourcing should therefore only be used internally in the corresponding aggregate or in the context of CQRS to build related read models.

`Domain events`, on the other hand, represent a specific fact or happening that is relevant regardless of the type of persistence strategy for aggregates, for example, for integrating bounded contexts.

Event sourcing and domain events can of course be used both at the same time, but should not influence each other. The two concepts are used for different purposes and should therefore not be mixed.

Please, read from the link below to learn more: [check here](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/domain-events-versus-event-sourcing/)

Comment: Event Sourcing is about one (or several) application design, while event-driven architecture is about all applications landscape (it is an evolution of SOA)

Comment: @Mayank Tripathi, could you add at least  a summary to your answer, in case the link breaks in the future?  (As mentioned in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259, "Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.")

Comment: @Mabyn I read the reference article and while this is very informative, this is not the correct way to answer a question. This should either move to comment or please, consider writing an answer based on what you have perceived.

Comment: @Arefe +1 That is exactly what I said. I think you meant to @ the author ;-)

Comment: @Mabyn more and more people are using event-driven architecture these days, so, the question is important and well laid. While I don't know about these very well, I mark it and will write an answer at a later time.